# How can style text like this in wordpress

Tags: customization, text

I want to know how I can style the backgourund of text like this as shown in imgae
I snipt it from [here](https://lastminuteengineers.com/a4988-stepper-motor-driver-arduino-tutorial/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add span tag to text you want background for and apply css- background-color and font-style: italic on span

```
    <p><span class="red">VDD</span> GND is used for driving the internal logic circuitry</p>
```

Then add the following into your WordPress CSS (your theme will have a css file, but may have a place to add custom styles in the Dashboard).

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg);
    transform: skew(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help thank you